# Hibernate Onetomany self join adds unique constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I would like to add a one to many relationship of an entity with itself:

```
@Entity
public class Layer {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
private String parentId;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
private Set<Layer> siblings;    
}
```

This means that I want to get all the other entities sharing the same `parentId`. The reason I want it is because it would be easier to write queries for this entity.

The problem is that on database generation(`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create`) it also adds a unique constraint on the `PARENT_ID` column and I do not want that.

How do I keep hibernate from adding the unique constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping currently makes `children` reference their parent by the column `PARENT_ID`. In order to use something as a reference it has to be unique.

What you probably want to have is the children to reference their parent by its `id`.

This should do the trick:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = false, insertable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
private Set<Layer> children;
```

I'm not sure that you can have a `String parentId` as well.
First it maps to the same column as the `children` property, but with a different type: `id` is of type `Long`, while `parentId` which should reference it is of type `String`.

The normal way to do this would be to make a property `Layer parent` which `@ManyToOne` and `mappedBy` `children`.

Comment: I understand that ideally the joins should happen over primary/foreign keys. This is an exceptional case where I want to group all entities based on a common attribute. That attribute is not a primary key. Apparently this can be done if I don't have the unique constraint. The problem is that Hibernate adds the unique constraint.

Comment: Are you saying the children of a `Layer` should be all `Layer` instances with the same `parent_id`? Which of course would always include the `Layer` itself? Never seen anything like this.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Maybe "children" is not the best term. The better term would be "siblings". And yes, that list would also include itself.

Comment: If it actually works apart from the unique key (and foreign key, I guess), you can always use your own scripts to create the schema. At least for production deployment that is highly recommended anyway.

Comment: You are correct. That is the solution I went with in the end - generating/modifying the schema myself. Thanks!